# How do I change a switch in CoreData using Dynamic Tables (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, xcode6

I have an app that I am converting from objective-c to Swift and am also changing it to use dynamic (rather than static) tables. I can load the cells with entity rows but I have been unable to figure out how to reference the UISwitch value in the @IBAction function in order to save it to CoreData.

Can anyone point me to simple example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I resolved this by using both cellForRowAtIndexPath to load the cells from my data model in my custom UITableViewController class and the following code in my custom UITableViewCell class. (Probably this is what Mundi was suggesting but if so I did not understand him.)

```
class CREWTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func changedSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    var newDescription = self.myTextView.text // value from cell
    var newSwitchValue = self.mySwitch.on // value from cell

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Switch")
    var pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "(viewName = %@)",viewName)
    var pred2 = NSPredicate(format: "(switchDescription = %@)",newDescription)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: NSCompoundPredicateType.AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [pred1, pred2])
    // Execute the fetch request
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if let fetchResults = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [Switch]
    {
        var recordCount = 0
        recordCount = fetchResults.count

        if recordCount == 1 {
            var appConfig  = fetchResults [0]
            appConfig.switchValue = newSwitchValue
            if !managedObjectContext!.save(nil) {
                NSLog("Unresolved error ")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, link the `UISwitch` in your prototype cell to the `@IBAction` handler in the view controller. In the handler, determine the core data object and manipulate as desired.

Assuming you have a fetched results controller (recommended):

```
@IBAction didFlipSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView:tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
    let object = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Thing
    thing.flag = sender.on
}
```

*Addition*:

Pursuant to your question: If you are not using a fetched results controller (though this is **not** recommended), you are presumably using an Array like `[Thing]`. You would replace the one line with something like:

```
let object = dataArray[indexPath.row] // no need to cast to Thing
```

Second, if you need access to other values in the cell, you can get to the cell and its elements with

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
let textToRetrieve = cell.textField?.text
```

However, this is not a good method, because you are getting data from your UI elements. Instead **you should always store the data in your model**, not in a table view row!

Thus, the proper text attribute of your `Thing` should already have been set by the `UITextFieldDelegate` implementation. (You can get the indexPath and thence the desired object in pretty much the same way as above, with `convertPoint` and `indexPathForRowAtPoint`.)

Consequently, when you flip the switch and retrieve the Core Data object as shown above, the text attribute be readily available (though you will probably not need it).

Comment: Mundi, thanks. this is very helpful but I don't use a fetched results controller (will consider it later). Without that I need to get the value of the key (UITextView) field in the cell in order to get the correct CoreData row. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You raise a number of issues, so I updated my answer to address them.

Comment: Mundi, I store my data in the data model (not an array) but I need to update it when the user changes the switch in the tableview. The cell contains two fields ... the textview which is the key for the entity in the data model and the switch (which is an attribute). What I want to do is update the switch setting in the data model. I'm sorry if I didn't make this clear. (My present approach is to fetch the row from the entity but I need the textview as part of the predicate.)

Comment: This is a disaster. Please implement `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: If I implement it how do I specify the predicate? That is one part that I don't understand.

Comment: It's just like a fetch request. The predicate depends on your data model. If you get the data from your table view from Core Data already, you should know how to do it.

Comment: I think you do not get my confusion. I know how to use a predicate to select data from my CoreData, I do not know how to get the value from the tableviewcell to build the predicate and if you are explaining how to get it I do not see it. However, I now believe that what I am doing is completely wrong and that I need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath instead.I believe that will give me access to all of the fields in the cell.

Comment: No, sorry, I showed you how to get the cell from a handler (`@IBAction`) of a control in the cell. It has nothing to do with predicates! The fetched results controller already gives you the object belonging to the index path. Selecting cells is something entirely different.